# Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ 2nd edition, Chapter 5 Drill - Program not throwing an exception when expected

Tags: c++, error-handling, outofrangeexception

In Stroustrup's book, the chapter 5 drill has a small program where you insert selections that have purposeful errors in order to better understand error handling. One of the inserts is as follows:

```
vector<char> v(5); for (int i=0; i<=v.size(); ++i) ; cout << "Success!\n";
```

Placed into the larger code, it looks like this:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
  try {
    vector<char> v(5);
    for (int i=0; i<=v.size(); ++i) ;
    cout << "Success!\n";
    return 0;
  }
  catch (exception& e){
    cerr<<"error: "<<e.what()<<'\n';
    return 1;
  }
  catch (...){
    cerr<<"Oops: unknown exception!\n";
    return 2;
  }
```

I can fix the code just fine. To fix it, I remove the improper semicolon in the middle of the for statement, and I *ostensibly* change the <= to a < operator in the for statement so it doesn't result in a range error. This compiles and prints 5 "Success!" to the terminal.

The problem is that if I modify the program to retain the range error in order to see how that error would be handled, I still don't get an exception. If, for example, I simply remove the semicolon and leave the <= as is, it prints "Success!" 6 times. If I even make it do so for i<=v.size()+10, it still prints out "Success!" many times.

My understanding from Stroustrup is that this should *not* be how this is handled. It should throw an exception because <= makes it read 6 indexes for vector v and the 6th index should be out of range.

Can anyone help me understand why this program is *not* throwing an exception for the range error and *not* having any sort of problem?

I am using g++ as my compiler on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 that I installed for the express purpose of learning to code. No special compiler arguments are used. Just "g++ -o NAME CODE.cpp".

Comment: There is no range error. You are not using the vector in the loop. And certainly not v.at()

Comment: There's nothing in the code that would cause an exception. The author presumably left that out by mistake.

Comment: Q: How can you get a range error with the vector ... if you're not actually *DOING* anything with the vector?  Like writing to it, or reading from it?

Comment: OK. I understand. So because nothing in the loop itself is trying actually *read* that index, it isn't a problem, even though it's running for that many times. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the code has been updated for this errata.

Comment: Accessing a vector, which isn't even used!, using [] outside its range just produces UB,  an exception is not required. To get range checking you need to use `at()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I seems as if the intention was to highlight that error, but the code doesn't actually produce the error. It has taught me, in any case, that it isn't a problem to use such a condition in the for statement. Though it seems like it's probably a bad habit regardless.

Comment: It’s ironic that Stroustrup was trying to write an error, but a typo made it run. There are lots of other cases in the text which are the exact opposite. The book has lots of typos/mistakes (at least my copy does), so you have to take it with a grain of salt. It’s a huge source of information, but you do have to see passed the mistakes.

Comment: I will bear that in mind, Blair. Thank you.